# How to reuse deps for different tests in Bazel?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, bazel, bazel-rules

I am using Bazel to compile scala.

Right now, my scala_test looks like

```
scala_test {
    name = "sample",
    srcs = [
            "a.scala",
            "b.scala",
            "c.scala",
            "d.scala",
    ],
    deps = [
            "//src//main/scala/.../dep1",
            "//src//main/scala/.../dep2",
            "//src//main/scala/.../dep3",
            "//src//main/scala/.../dep4",
    ]
}
```

In this case, Bazel does not support parallelization on these srcs as they are grouped as one `scala_test`. To enable automatic parallel testing, I would like to separate srcs into different `scala_test` like

```
scala_test {
    name = "sample1",
    srcs = [
            "a.scala",
    ],
    deps = [
            "//src//main/scala/.../dep1",
            "//src//main/scala/.../dep2",
            "//src//main/scala/.../dep3",
            "//src//main/scala/.../dep4",
    ]
}
scala_test {
    name = "sample2",
    srcs = [
            "b.scala",
    ],
    deps = [
            "//src//main/scala/.../dep1",
            "//src//main/scala/.../dep2",
            "//src//main/scala/.../dep3",
            "//src//main/scala/.../dep4",
    ]
}
...
```

The problem is I guess bazel tries to compile the deps for every `scala_test`. Is there any way to group dependencies and reuse them in different `scala_test` blocks such as `scala_library`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I think Bazel caches the dependencies so I don't have to worry about compiling them again when running all tests.